# Is this website phishing SE?

Tags: discussion

I was redirected from a web search to `tex DOT dingding DOT com`, which appears to be a mirror of tex.SE.  I only noticed the URL when it asked me to log in.

Wait…  Did I just mention I was about to give my login/pwd ?

I'm pretty sure this website isn't legit — or is it ?

Comment: Probably not, get in contact with the SE team. They will take action.

Comment: Right, but I thought it would be better to advertise it to SE users as well meanwhile.

Comment: Good thinking :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [A website-importing clone](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/5962/5764)

Answer (score 2):

This happens.

If a site provides copies of SE-related content, it needs to adhere to two simple rules:

- Attribution: You have to provide [attribution](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). Simple links to the original post and author info are just fine.
- Subsequent re-use: You have to allow other people to use your content, as long as they follow these very same rules.

If it doesn't you can report it. Read more about it in [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/168244)